# Looking for a product that allows building dashboards, duplicating them, changing the data source of a duplicated dashboard and embedding it via url

Tags: charts, analytics, dashboard, embedding

Today we are using Mongo Atlas and Charts to store some data, build a dashboard accordingly, and then we are using the embed to option to display the charts on a Notion page. This notion page is dedicated to a customer.

We have a backend process that creates a new DB with up-to-date data and we'd like to easily duplicate the previous dashboard, change the data source to the new DB and embed it on a new Notion page.

I want to do as much as possible of this process automatically, already tested Quicksight and Metabase and they don't seem to provide a good solution for it.
I'm gonna try also looker and tableau soon, and I thought it can be a good idea to ask here if someone is familiar with a proper solution.

Thanks

Comment: Hey Tom! I came here to ask the same question. I was using Metabase, but it doesn't provide a solution to duplicating a dashboard for multiple data sources on a single metabase instance. There has been a request for it since 2017, which hasn't been closed to date & doesn't seem likely to be completed anytime soon. 

I'll be trying out Apache Superset over the next week. 

Meanwhile, let us know if you find any solution

Comment: Thanks @AdityaMishra I’ll test Tableau and will update with the outcome